# APT-KEY GPG --recv-key process hangs without any network traffic

Tags: debian, apt, mysql, gpg, apt-key

On Debian 11, running as root. I am attempying to add the mysql repository public key (due to the expiry in Feb) and update to mysql 8.0, but every apt-key or gpg command I run just HANGS.

Even adding `-v` provides no extra output. A packet capture shows no network traffic being generated. Absolutely no logs on the system during this time.

Commands I've attempted so far:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 3A79BD29
gpg -v --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 467B942D3A79BD29
gpg -v --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 3A79BD29
```

The GPG commands don't even have an output, it just immediately hangs.

The ultimate problem I am trying to solve:

```
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease                                                                                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
```

I pulled the original apt-key command from their documentation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Anyone know what is happening? How can I find out why these commands are hanging?

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently pgpkeys.mit.edu is just down for keys. Despite the site being accessible from the server, gpg and apt-key cant access it (giving error timed out).
Manually added key from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-gpg-signature.html

But GPG doesnt affect apt for some reason, so I guess you have to use the DEPRECATED apt-key add *file* for it to work.